# BuddyPress - Get a List of Defined xProfile fields

Tags: buddypress

"How can I retrieve all xProfile fields?"

Comment: A better question would be: "How can I retrieve all xProfile fields?"

Comment: "How can I retrieve all xProfile fields?" :)

Comment: if it works for you, you can mark it as an answer, so that it do not appears in Unanswered list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the user id in Bp Profile loop to get hold of alll the fields and their values.

```
<?php
if ( bp_has_profile(array('user_id' => 1)) ) :
 while ( bp_profile_groups() ) : bp_the_profile_group(); ?>

<ul id="profile-groups"> <?php
 if ( bp_profile_group_has_fields() ) : ?>

  <li>
    <?php bp_the_profile_group_name() ?>

    <ul id="profile-group-fields">
    <?php while ( bp_profile_fields() ) : bp_the_profile_field(); ?>

      <?php if ( bp_field_has_data() ) : ?>
      <li>
        <?php bp_the_profile_field_name() ?>
        <?php bp_the_profile_field_value() ?>
      </li>
      <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
  <li>

<?php endif; ?>
</ul>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

<div id="message" class="info">
   <p>This user does not have a profile.</p>
 </div>

<?php endif;?>
```

This will give you group name and all the fields name, with values

Comment: One thing though, how do I get them into an array?

Comment: you can use bp_get_the_profile_field_input_name, bp_get_the_profile_field_value to store them in a variable instead of directly echoing them.